# $f(z)=\int_0^\infty \int_0^\infty e^{-x^{\frac{\pi}{z}}-y^{\frac{\pi}{\pi -z}}}\, dx\, dy$

Tags: integration, complex-analysis

I encountered this double integral,
$$\int_0^\infty \int_0^\infty e^{-x^{\frac{\pi}{z}}-y^{\frac{\pi}{\pi -z}}}\, dx\, dy,$$
which is strikingly similar to
$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty \int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-x^2-y^2}\, dx\, dy$$
which can be solved by noticing that $-x^2-y^2=-\left(x^2+y^2\right)$ corresponds to $-r^2$ in polar coordinates – such double integral is equal to $\pi$.

But what should I do when there are functions in the exponents (rather than $2$s)? Can there be applied some trick analogous to transform to polar coordinates?

Also, the double integral should converge if and only if $0\lt \operatorname{Re}z\lt \pi$.

Comment: www.wolframalfa.com says: $\frac{(\pi -z) z \csc (z)}{\pi }$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is quite easy if you are familiar with
the [Gamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function).
Now, let me assume that $0<\Re(z)<\pi$, so both integrals
$$
\int_0^\infty e^{-x^{\frac{\pi}{z}}} \, dx,
\qquad
\int_0^\infty e^{-y^{\frac{\pi}{\pi-z}}} \, dy
$$
are absolutely convergent, and we can take our integral as a repeated integral.
Let's calculate the first integral
$$
\int_0^\infty e^{-x^{\frac{\pi}{z}}} \, dx.
$$
To do so, recall the following well known identity for the Gamma function
$$
\int_0^\infty t^{s-1} e^{-t} \, dt = \Gamma(s)
$$
where $\Re(s)>0$. The idea is to reduce our integral to this form.
Indeed, the most evident change of variable
$$
t = x^{\frac{\pi}{z}},
\quad
dt = \frac{\pi}{z}\,x^{\frac{\pi}{z}-1}\,dx = \frac{\pi}{z}\,t^{-\frac{z}{\pi}+1}\,dx
$$
gives
$$
\int_0^\infty e^{-x^{\frac{\pi}{z}}} \, dx = \frac{z}{\pi} \, \int_0^\infty t^{\frac{z}{\pi}-1}\,e^{-t} \, dt
= \frac{z}{\pi} \, \Gamma\biggl(\frac{z}{\pi}\biggr) = \Gamma\biggl(\frac{z+\pi}{\pi}\biggr).
$$
In a similar fashion we get
$$
\int_0^\infty e^{-y^{\frac{\pi}{\pi-z}}} \, dy
=\frac{\pi}{\pi-z}\,\Gamma\biggl(\frac{\pi}{\pi-z}\biggr)
=\Gamma\biggl(\frac{2\pi-z}{\pi}\biggr).
$$
Now
$$
\int_0^\infty \int_0^\infty e^{-x^{\frac{\pi}{z}}-y^{\frac{\pi}{\pi -z}}}\, dx\, dy = 
\Gamma\biggl(\frac{z+\pi}{\pi}\biggr)\,
\Gamma\biggl(\frac{2\pi-z}{\pi}\biggr)
$$
assuming $0<\Re(z)<\pi$.